# Why are there extra ASM instructions in a naked Rust function?

Tags: x86, rust, wrapper, abi

I am wrapping a low level ABI in Rust, taking advantage of the `naked` function feature. Here is my code and relevant disassembly

```
#![feature(asm)]
#![feature(naked_functions)]

struct MyStruct {
    someVar: i64, // not important
                  // ...
}

impl MyStruct {
    #[naked]
    extern "C" fn wrap(&self) {
        unsafe {
            asm!("NOP" :::: "volatile");
            // not sure if the volatile option is needed, but I
            // figured it wouldn't hurt
        }
    }
}
```

Disassembled with LLDB:

```
ABIWrap`ABIWrap::{{impl}}::wrap:
  * 0x100001310 <+0>:  movq   %rdi, -0x10(%rbp)
  * 0x100001314 <+4>:  movq   %rsi, -0x8(%rbp)
  * 0x100001318 <+8>:  movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rax
  * 0x10000131c <+12>: movq   -0x8(%rbp), %rcx
  * 0x100001320 <+16>: movq   %rax, -0x20(%rbp)
  * 0x100001324 <+20>: movq   %rcx, -0x18(%rbp)
    0x100001328 <+24>: nop    
    0x100001329 <+25>: retq   
    0x10000132a <+26>: nopw   (%rax,%rax)
```

The 6 lines preceding the NOP (I've marked with `*`) are what I am confused by. Shouldn't the `naked` directive leave, for lack of a better term, a naked function?

I am attempting to allow the arguments to just pass through this function to the ABI as it follows roughly the same calling convention as Rust, I just need to swap one or two of the registers, hence the inline assembly.

Is there a way to get rid of these 6 preceding instructions? I am calling against the ABI a lot and the previous way I was calling against it was causing a decent amount of overhead. I want to make sure that the registers containing any important values aren't overwritten.

Side note: is the "volatile" option needed? I wasn't sure but added it anyways.

Comment: I don't know - but just as a sanity check: you decompiled a _release_ build yes?

Comment: No, I am decompiling the debug build

Comment: For my own curiosity, what ABI is this and on what platform?

Comment: Looks eerily like its jumping back into some shadow space to grab some data which is what the 64-bit Windows ABI specifies.. kinda hard to tell though. @ChaseWalden for my curiosity as well (I haven't looked into the inner workings of naked functions in Rust) what happens when you don't embed the function in an implementation of a struct. What if its just a pure function out on its own? I'm wondering whether that "prelude" there is pulling `self` from somewhere.

Comment: @Shepmaster, you are right. it is asm! not asm. I retyped my code in my question rather than copy and paste. It is asm! in my actual code, just a mild typo in my actual question. Also, the ABI is an old package that I wrote to interface with one of my embedded projects. Its not very clean and I haven't released it since it's just for one board I made. I am trying to use the ABI I already have implemented as rewriting it would be a lot of refactoring on the board firmware and the interfacing library

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, I suspect you are right about that. I am thinking that it may have something to do with the prelude for self, but I was wondering if there was a way to eliminate it completely.

Comment: Upon further research, it looks like this may be a bug (or is it a feature?). Not a direct match to this scenario, but similar. Here is the Issue ticket https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34043

Comment: @ChaseWalden: I think you have found your answer, there is no point in naked functions taking arguments, since using those arguments require an agreement on how they are passed (ABI) which is at odds with the `naked` attribute which specifies not to assume any ABI.

Comment: @MatthieuM: I would partially agree on that. It is not necessarily that it doesn't assume an ABI, just that the pro/epilogue are skipped on code generation. I would suggest reading the naked fn PR, specifically this comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1201#issuecomment-121248070. In other languages, like D, arguments can be passed, it is up to the developer to handle the parameter passing

Comment: In Rust, you can specify the ABI to use when calling a naked function. That's what the `extern "C"` does in the example. This only affects the code generated at the call site. It's up to the function implementor to follow the declared ABI inside the function.Importantly, if you don't specify an ABI for a naked function, you can't even call it from inside Rust, since Rust doesn't know what to do at the call site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After tinkering with this more, (and figuring how to effectively disassemble my release build), I found that the extra instructions are only added during the debug build (or at least when -O0).

When compiling the code with -O2, I found that all of the assembly was inlined, but that is easily fixed with an `#[inline(never)]` directive. Now the arguments are being passed correctly without the extra instructions ruining my registers :)

Now I just need to have the code only run -O2 on just these functions and not the rest of the debug build...

Comment: It may be worth opening an issue for this :)

Comment: @MatthieuM: Possibly... I am still trying to figure out what the purpose of moving the arguments onto the stack is. I am almost starting to think that what SimonWhitehead in the above comment thread suggested, that the callee is storing the values in "shadow space" which is strange since I am on a Mac